# Получить текст с экрана

Tags: c#, wpf, uwp, gdi+, tesseract

Я переписываю код WPF в UWP. Задача состоит в том, чтобы сделать скриншот экрана, вырезать его и скормить его библиотеке, которая найдет текст с фото.

библиотека с которой работаю - tesseract-ocr https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/.

Мой код в WPF ниже:

```
// Делаю скрин и обрезаю его
// _bounds.Width = 1920, _bounds.Height = 1080;
using (Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap((int)_bounds.Width, (int)_bounds.Height))
{
    using (Graphics graph = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
    {
        graph.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, bmp.Size);

        // save for check result
        bmp?.Save($@"{_rootFullImage}\{_counter.ToString()}.jpg");

        // XPosition, YPosition, WidthPosition, HeightPosition - values how cut it
        Bitmap clippedBitMap = bmp?.Clone(new Rectangle((int)XPosition, (int)YPosition, (int)WidthPosition, (int)HeightPosition), bmp.PixelFormat);

        // save for check result
        clippedBitMap?.Save($@"{_rootCutImage}\{_counter.ToString()}.jpg");

        string ocrText;
        using (TesseractEngine engine = new TesseractEngine(@"./tessdata", "eng", EngineMode.Default))
        {
            using (Pix img = Tesseract.PixConverter.ToPix(clippedBitMap))
            {
                using (Page page = engine.Process(img))
                {
                    ocrText = page.GetText();
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Bitmap and Graphics - используют "System.Drawing", UWP не работает с ним. Главная задача получить текст с экрана, если есть, что-то лучше tesseractа - предлагайте. Объект Pix имеет следующий конструктор:

[image]

Помогите кто может плиз.

Comment: Скриншот окна вашего приложения или экрана вне вашего окна?

Comment: Это смотрели? https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/screen-capture

Comment: [Take a screenshot](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/screen-capture#take-a-screenshot)

Answer (score 2):

Tesseract работает только c изображением в формате Tiff. Вам сначала нужно конвертировать изображение в Tiff, а дальше передавать его в engine.Process(Pix.LoadTiffFromMemory(tiffImageBytes));

Вам это не нужно: Pix img = Tesseract.PixConverter.ToPix(clippedBitMap).

Comment: У автора как раз-таки проблема с получением изображения. То есть конвертировать нечего.